# C# Windows Forms, do not show a form in taskbar, but make it go on front when a form that is shown there is focused

Tags: c#, windows, forms, taskbar

I am making an application which will have an interface similar to Photoshop: multiple separate forms all help edit an object. So, i'll have multiple forms, one of which is "main" (provides file menu, settings menu, about etc) and others have controls that edit the object opened in main form.

Lets say for simplicity this is a text editor and i have MainForm and StyleForm. Now, what i need is for the whole application to show as one "bar" in the windows taskbar. This could be achieved by setting ShowInTaskbar to false for StyleForm, but then if i, say, focus other application, then focus my application, only MainForm will get on top of other windows, StyleForm will remain hidden under the window of the application i focused previously.

I found answer here [Make all forms associated with a program come to the front when one form is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011204/make-all-forms-associated-with-a-program-come-to-the-front-when-one-form-is-sele) but it imports a dll. Maybe there is a .net solution for this?

Also, i'd like to display something different in the taskbar, not the MainForm's caption, is that possible?

Comment: if both of these forms do exists in same process (same exe project or dll project) then cant you invoke a delegate and make the form also visible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I set the second form to `ShowInTaskBar = false`, set the `FormBorderStyle` to `SizableToolWindow` and then created it using the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Owner = this;  // <-- This is the important thing
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

This makes the subform `F2` stay on top of `Form1` and hides and shows it when the `Form1` is hidden and shown.

**EDIT**
Oh, I used Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4 Client Profile if that's important. This should work with other versions, however.

Comment: +1. Also in [Form.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) remarks is written the behavior of forms when property is set.

Comment: Owner is a barely used property because it's possible to pass the owner form directly to the Show method. Like in `f2.Show(this);`

Comment: @Steve: True, but I used it here to explicitly point the OP to the `Owner` property, which is the key to the solution of his problem.

Comment: Huh? Strange this wasnt suggested in the topic i linked. This is indeed simple solution, almost feel stupid asking... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

In the main window, you could catch the Focus event and then for each subform call the BringToFront method

Comment: Thats obvious, but it introduces flickering, as described in the topic i linked...